# How to enable infinispan cache in Hibernate properties file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, infinispan

I am using below properties entries in applicationcontext.xml file you can check entry of property tag

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cc" />
        <property name="user" value="hariom" />
        <property name="password" value="om123" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"> </property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"> </property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory"></property>


    </bean>
```

I am trying to activate second level cache but i am getting esxception

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ccc.spring.dao.RegistrationDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Nested property in path 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ccc.spring.dao.RegistrationDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Nested property in path 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Nested property in path 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Nested property in path 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Nested property in path 'hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:915)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:912)
    ... 48 more
```

What i am  doing wrong in configuration ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Exception again.

> Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Remove `hibernate.cache.*` properties from the configuration because as per exception it's not a valid property of `ComboPooledDataSource`. This is part of **TransactionManager**.

Please have a look at this thread [Provide transactional support for Infinispan 2nd level cache](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9087) and find the configuration as well.

Comment: Can we add second level cache property here

Comment: No you can't add it under `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` bean because it's the property of Hibernate Transaction Manager. Add it under transaction manager bean.